# Как определить недостающее число в массиве?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пишу панель управления, в которой пользователь может определённые блоки менять местами (использую [Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/))

У каждого блока есть свой *id* (эти id и перечисляются в строке, который у нас выступает исходным).

Пользователь может удалять и добавлять новые блоки.

Нужна функция добавления нового блока. Что бы задать *id* для нового блока -- нужно проверить все существующие блоки и вернуть один *id* из числа недостающих, либо, если все идут по порядку, вернуть следующий id, который идет по порядку.

Есть строка: *1, 2, 3, 5*.

**Вопрос № 1:** Как определить недостающее число в этой строке?

**Вопрос № 2:** Если в строке нет "недостающих чисел", как вернуть следующее число, которое должно идти по порядку, чтобы продолжить счёт.

**Вопрос № 3:** Как заставить всё это работать, если числа в исходной строке могут быть не по порядку?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48455/discussion-on-question-by-di------).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Преобразует массив к полному -

```js
const compare = (a, b) => a - b;

source.sort(compare);

if (source.length === source[source.length - 1]) {
  // если мы тут то пропусков в массиве нет
  source.push(source.length + 1);
} else {
  let resultLength = source[source.length - 1] + 1; // длина будет равнятся самому большому значению

  source.length = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i < resultLength; i++) {
    source.push(i);
  }
}

let source = [7, 2];

console.log(source);
```

Содержит только недостаяющие цифры -

```js
const compare = (a, b) => a - b;

let result = [];

source.sort(compare);

if( source.length === source[ source.length - 1] ){
  // если мы тут то пропусков в массиве нет
  result.push( source.length + 1 );
}else{
  let resultLength = source[ source.length - 1 ] + 1; // длина будет равнятся самому большому значению
  
  for(let i = 1; i < resultLength; i++ ){
    if( source.indexOf( i ) === -1 ){
      result.push(  i  );
    }
  }
}


let source = [ 7, 1, 2 ];

console.log( result );
```

Возвращается первое отсутствующие число отсчитанное от единицы -

```js
const compare = (a, b) => a - b;


function containNot(array) {
  array.sort(compare);

  if (array.length === array[array.length - 1]) {
    return array.length + 1;
  } else {
    let resultLength = array[array.length - 1] + 1;

    for (let i = 1; i < resultLength; i++) {
      if (array.indexOf(i) === -1) {
        return i;
      }
    }
  }
}

let source = [1, 2, 3, 5, 11];

console.log(containNot(source));
```

Comment: Почти то, что нужно. Этот код возвращает все числа. А как добавить того, чтобы возвращалось только одно число? Например, если у нас исходные число 2, 7 -- вернуть нужно только 1. А если 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 и 7 -- то вернуть нужно 8.

Comment: Воу, очень здорово. Только вот, если задать исходные числа 7, 2 -- возвращает 3. Хотя, по логике должно вернуть 1.

Comment: Может в начале исходные числа нужно расставить по порядку? Просто в строке они могут задаваться в разных порядках.

Comment: @Di-, и как вы хотите определять какой должен быть порядок?

Comment: @Grundy Вообще я пишу панель управления, в которой пользователь может определённые блоки менять местами. У каждого блока есть свой id (эти id и перечисляются в массиве, который у нас выступает исходным). Пользователь может удалять и добавлять новые блоки. Вот я и пытаюсь сделать функцию добавления нового блока. Что бы задать id для нового блока -- нужно проверить все существующие блоки и вернуть один id из числа недостающих, либо, если все идут по порядку, вернуть следующий id, который идет по порядку.

Comment: @Di-, стоит перенести это описание в вопрос

Comment: @Grundy OlmerDale обновил функцию и всё заработало. Спасибо огромное.

Comment: @Di-, в любом случае, нужно отредактировать вопрос, и, возможно, заголовок. Чтобы будущим посетителям было понятно о чем речь идет. Сейчас по вопросу этого непонятно

Comment: @Grundy, согласен. Сейчас отредактирую, спасибо.

Comment: @OlmerDale, слушай, а если у нас числа заключены в кавычки, то возвращается строка с числами от 1 до 40. Как быть в этом случае?

Comment: `"1, 5, 10".split(  ","  ) ` и дальше `parseFloat`.

Comment: @OlmerDale Если задаю числ  let source = [1,2,3,5,11], то возвращает 6. Хотя, по идее, должно быть 4. Если задаю [1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], то возвращает 10.

Comment: @OlmerDale Да. Теперь всё работает как нужно. Но сейчас не могу корректно передать свои данные в `source`, которые собираются "на лету". Как я понимаю, проблема в том, что у меня строковый массив, а не числовой. `let source = parseFloat(positionArr);` возвращает `Uncaught TypeError: array.sort is not a function(…)`

Comment: @Di- `parseFloat` преобразует строку в число, а Вы в нее массив передаете. пройдитесь по массиву со строками и преобразуйте в числа  , а затем уже используйте -  `let indexAll = source.map( parseFloat );`

Comment: @OlmerDale, Блин, какой же я пень в javascript. Правильно преобразовывать через `valueOf`?

Comment: @Di- я же Вам показал как нужно..

Comment: @OlmerDale 
`$.each(positionArr, function(index,value) {
  parseFloat(value);
  let indexAll = source.map(parseFloat);
});`
Примерно так?

Comment: я не знаю как именно нужно Вам. У показал что нужно сделать имея массив со строками.  А Вы показываете что-то что может придти в голову человеку, который не прочел ни одной книги и просто пытается собрать шатл методом тыка.

Comment: @OlmerDale Понял. Чтобы перебрать массив используем `for (var i in positionArr)`. Затем каждый элемент массива мы пропускаем через parseFloat: `parseFloat(i)`. Верно же?

Comment: нет!  Я же показал как нужно сделать. :)

Comment: @OlmerDale Мы внутри `parseFloat` должны пройти по массиву?

Comment: Вы начинаете вопросы по кругу задавать. Прочтите первый сегодняшний ответ и получите ответ на последний.

Comment: @OlmerDale `var indexAll = positionArr.map(function (item) {
  return parseFloat(item);
});`? :-)

Comment: @OlmerDale Ахаха, как же всё просто) `positionArr.map(parseFloat)`..

Comment: ну да, `map` проходится по исходному массиву и возвращает новый. В качестве значения она принимает функцию, которая в качестве результата возвращает будущий элемент нового массива. А `parseFloat` функция которая принимает строку и возвращает число. Вот и скармливаем `parseFloat` чтобы получить новый массив с числами. Это надо в хелпе читать. Начали с массивами работать, не пожалейте время, пару часов прочитать о всех методах.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь. Без вас ничего бы не получилось. :-)